# How to return a queryable sub-instance of a TableQuery?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick-3.0

I'm trying to build an function which takes an optional sort or filter attribute for a query and apply these on a TableQuery if the attribute exists, if not, returns something queryable on which I can then apply other filters.

What I want to end up with is something like this:

```java
MyTableInstance.applySearchTerm(termOption).applySorting(sortOption).filter(do other stuff here)
```

What I came up with until now is this:

```java
  private implicit def applySearchTerm[U <: Query[IssueDao#IssueTable, Issue, Seq]](table: U)(
      term: Option[String]): U =
    term match {
      case Some(term) => table.filter(_.title === term)
      case None => table
    }


  private def applyFilters(filters: Filters) =
    IssueTable.applySearchTerm(filters.term)
```

From what I understand, the `TableQuery` extends the `Query` class, while calling `filter` or other query methods returns a `Query[T, T#TableElementType,Seq]`, so what I tried was defining an upper type bound and return this, but this gives me

```
[error]  found   : slick.lifted.Query[dao.IssueDao#IssueTable,models.Issue,Seq]
[error]  required: U
[error]       case Some(term) => table.filter(_.title === term)
```

I'm not quite sure what the error here is. Is the compiler complaining because the returned value is no upper type bound but the exact type?

I saw a solution proposing implementing a custom trait which seems to solve this problem, but I'm not sure this is the best way and I try to understand how these type limitations are applied in Scala.

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We would need more code to make sure, but I am almost certain that the main issue  why you cannot easily refactor this is because you have `IssueTable` inside class `IssueDao` class - basically path-dependent types make some things of different types while you think they are of the same type. And usage of `#` doesn't solve all the issues.